# UrlFetchApp xml payload fails while posting to Harvest

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using a Google Apps Script to generate an invoice in Harvest. This script worked as a charm but suddenly it doesn't any more.

Function I use to post to Harvest:

```
function postInvoiceToHarvest(xml){

  var USERNAME = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('username');
  var PASSWORD = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('password');
  var url = "https://acme.harvestapp.com/invoices/";
  var headers = {
      "Accept": "application/xml",
      "Content-Type": "application/xml",
      "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD)};

  var options = {
      "method" : "post",
      "headers" : headers,
      "payload" : xml,
      "muteHttpExceptions": true};

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
   Logger.log('Response Code: ' + response.getResponseCode());
}
```

log:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://acme.harvestapp.com/invoices/, {headers={Authorization=Basic xxxxxx, Content-Type=application/xml, Accept=application/xml}, payload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invoice>
<client-id type="integer">123</client-id>
<currency>Euro - EUR</currency>
<subject>Invoice</subject>
<notes>My Note</notes>
<number>123</number>
<kind>subscription</kind>
<csv-line-items>"kind","description","quantity","unit_price","amount","taxed","taxed2","project_id"
"subscription","subscription 1",11,6,66,false,false,0</csv-line-items>
</invoice>

, method=post}]) [0,784 seconden]
```

This fails. And it looks like the xml payload doesn't get send properly anymore.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the support!

Comment: what errors are you getting

Comment: I got this error. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <request> <message>You must provide a valid client for the invoice</message> </request> But I have the feeling that the payload wasn't posted. I would like to check that, but don't know how.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, create a test client in Harvest and try to send. Looks like the problem is going to be with harvest and not apps script.

Comment: Harvest says it is a Google problem, and that they are: "not able to troubleshoot beyond confirming that the API works correctly – sorry about this!" So it looks like I am stuck in limbo here. If I could only see what the output is / is posted by Google.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm stuck with this too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work!  Turns out you just have to be VERY particular with your headers.

```
 var invoicePayload = JSON.stringify(invoice);

    var options = {
      'headers': {
        "Accept": "application/json", // required!
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' pass),

    },
      contentType: "application/json", // required!
      contentLength: (invoicePayload.length + 2).toString(), // required! 
      // (added 2 for quotes, seemed to be other clients did this and it worked
      'method': 'post',
      'payload': invoicePayload, // json string 
      followRedirects: false,
      muteHttpExceptions: true

  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://subdomain.harvestapp.com/invoices", options);
```

You can do this with XML too, just change the content/accept to application/xml and your content length to match.  Those are the three key headers here.  Excluding the "Accept" will redirect you to the Sign-In page, excluding the content-type or length will give you a "Client Id is required" message.